# Getting the referrer's web server name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am placing a JS file to remote server(s). I d like to know where the request is coming from.

ie : i have a js on google.com and upon user click on the link that s produced by js, it triggers some c# code on my server, but i also have the same js on yahoo.com and i d like to be able to know where the request is coming from.

How to find this ?

Comment: Can you just use the referrer header or are you looking to do tracking with a query string or something similar?

Comment: I dont want to bother with that but i think i found it on  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables[key.ToString()] just need to find the key for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ASP.NET, the referring page is given by `Request.UrlReferrer` as a [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) object.

This is also available as `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]` as a string.

Answer (score 9):

`System.Environment.MachineName` should contain the name of the server.

Comment: This answer isn't correct for the question which is asking for the referrers domain name.  However, it's exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]
```

Also you may need:

```
Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on your own lead for "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables", the MSDN documentation for the [ServerVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx) property contains some sample code on how to retrieve all available named server variables:

```
int loop1, loop2;
NameValueCollection coll;

// Load ServerVariable collection into NameValueCollection object.
coll=Request.ServerVariables; 
// Get names of all keys into a string array. 
String[] arr1 = coll.AllKeys; 
for (loop1 = 0; loop1 < arr1.Length; loop1++) 
{
   Response.Write("Key: " + arr1[loop1] + "<br>");
   String[] arr2=coll.GetValues(arr1[loop1]);
   for (loop2 = 0; loop2 < arr2.Length; loop2++) {
      Response.Write("Value " + loop2 + ": " + Server.HtmlEncode(arr2[loop2]) + "<br>");
   }
}
```

Furthermore, it also contains a link to all server variables supported by IIS

- [IIS Server Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx)

For example, the "REMOTE_HOST" variable will give you:

> The name of the host that is making the request. If the server does not have this information, it will set REMOTE_ADDR and leave this empty.